# Displaying a "clear button" (delete button) in an iPhone webapp textbox

Tags: iphone, button, web-applications, textbox

I am creating an iPhone webapp with a textbox. I would like that textbox to display a "clear button" on the right side of the box... aka the round grey button with the X in it.

Is it possible to set a css or html property so safari handles this, or do i need to develop this ability on my own using an image and some code.

I know you can set the Clear Button property of a UITextBox for a native app, but this is a webapp i am creating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An input field of type "search" will bring up a rounded text box with a clear button marked "X".  That is the closest I have found without using javascript.

```
<input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="search" value="search me" />
```